# Improve performance of mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb

I have billions of documents to storage number of people to into department stores(man, woman, etc.) everyday

*id_department: position of department, area_type: branch name in department(like shoes, fashion, etc.)*

```
(_id:59e86325dc03580bdbf2347f    
date:20170906
id_department:2640
goinside_type:2
area_type:1)
(_id:59e86325dc03580bdbf2347f    
date:20170906
id_department:2642
goinside_type:3
area_type:2)
```

I want to write a query can returns number of people visit area_type in a time range, the issue here is area_type can be over 1000 and the condition of every area_type can be different(so can not use group by area_type in this case). My pipeline will be long and it will slow down the performance.

```
$pipeline = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [$match] => Array
                (
                    [id_station] => Array
                        (
                            [$in] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 2640
                                    [1] => 2642
                                    [2] => 2644
                                )

                        )
                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [$gte] => 20170802
                            [$lte] => 20170930
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [$group] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => Array
                        (
                            [id_station] => $id_station                            
                        )

                    [total_entries - area1] => Array
                        (
                            [$sum] => Array
                                (
                                    [$cond] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [$and] => Array
                                                        (    
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [$eq] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [0] => $area_type
                                                                            [1] => 1
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                            [2] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [$gte] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [0] => $date
                                                                            [1] => 20170901
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                            [3] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [$lte] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [0] => $date
                                                                            [1] => 20170930
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [1] => 1
                                            [2] => 0
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [total_entries - area1previous] => Array
                        (
                            [$sum] => Array
                                (
                                    [$cond] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [$and] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [$eq] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [0] => $area_type
                                                                            [1] => 1
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                            [2] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [$gte] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [0] => $date
                                                                            [1] => 20170802
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                            [3] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [$lte] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [0] => $date
                                                                            [1] => 20170831
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )
                                            [1] => 1
                                            [2] => 0
                                        )

                                )

                        )
                        [total_entries - area2] => Array
                        (
                            [$sum] => Array
                                (
                                    [$cond] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [$and] => Array
                                                        (    
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [$eq] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [0] => $area_type
                                                                            [1] => 2
                                                                        )

                                                                )                                                       

                                                            [2] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [$gte] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [0] => $date
                                                                            [1] => 20170901
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                            [3] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [$lte] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [0] => $date
                                                                            [1] => 20170930
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [1] => 1
                                            [2] => 0
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [total_entries - area2previous] => Array
                        (
                            [$sum] => Array
                                (
                                    [$cond] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [$and] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [$eq] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [0] => $area_type
                                                                            [1] => 2
                                                                        )

                                                                )                                                           
                                                            [2] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [$gte] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [0] => $date
                                                                            [1] => 20170802
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                            [3] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [$lte] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [0] => $date
                                                                            [1] => 20170831
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )
                                            [1] => 1
                                            [2] => 0
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )
)
 $cursor = $collection->aggregate($pipeline,  ['allowDiskUse' => true]);
```

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Your `id_department` should probably be called `id_station`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important thing here is that you create an index on the `date` and `id_department`/`id_station` (which I suspect are the same) fields.

```
collection.createIndex({
    "id_department" : 1,
    "date" : 1
})
```

This will speed up your `$match` stage after which only a few documents should be left to process for the following pipeline stage(s).

Once the resulting performance has been measured and proven not to be sufficient you can attempt to optimize your query (e.g. by extracting the repeteated date filter into an interim `$project` or `$group` stage right before the real grouping that you do already).

Comment: my mistake is create wrong index: "date, id_department" instead of "id_department, date"